# What are the products of partition numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In Neil Sloane's, On Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, A033637 is the sequence whose first few terms are:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, \
24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 40, 42, ...

There is no description of what is meant by the Title, Products of Partition Numbers.

Can someone describe the sequence, perhaps with an example?

Comment: It looks to be all the numbers which can be written as a product of partition numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is literally what the title says.

First $n$-th partition number (A000041) is the number of integer partitions of $n$. Let $A$ be the set of all partition numbers.

Now let $B$ be the set of all numbers that can be written as the product of elements of $A$. For example since $2, 3 \in A$, $2*3 = 6 \in B$.

Then A033637 is just the elements of $B$ in order.